# Twitter Bootstrap 2.0.1 Togglable tabs don't execute properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm having an issue right now when trying to use the Twitter Bootstrap Togglable tabs and having it display different div nodes.  Everything lays out properly (so I know CSS is hooked up right) and I have the JavaScript referenced and made sure that the functions I need are there, but for some reason when I click the tabs it doesn't display the other div's (based on the link clicked in the navigation field).

Here's the markup I'm trying to use

```
<script>
$(function () {
$('.tabs a:last').tab('show')
})
</script>

<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
        <li class="active"><a href="#home" data-toggle="tab">home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#about" data-toggle="tab">about tom</a></li>
        <li><a href="#services" data-toggle="tab">services</a></li>
        <li><a href="#new_patient" data-toggle="tab">new patients</a></li>
      </ul>

      <div class="tab-content" id="tab-content">
        <div class="tab-pane fade in active" id="home">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="slider-wrapper theme-default">
                    <div id="slider" class="nivoSlider">
                        <img src="i/6.jpg" alt="" />
                        <img src="i/1.jpg" alt="" />
                        <img src="i/2.jpg" alt="" />
                        <img src="i/3.jpg" alt="" />
                        <img src="i/4.jpg" alt="" />
                        <img src="i/5.jpg" alt="" />   
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="span4">
                        <h2>Heading</h2>
                            <p>Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Integer posuere erat a ante venenatis dapibus posuere velit aliquet. Aenean eu leo quam. Pellentesque ornare sem lacinia quam venenatis vestibulum. Duis mollis, est non commodo luctus, nisi erat porttitor ligula, eget lacinia odio sem nec elit.</p>
                            <p><a class="btn" href="#">View details &raquo;</a></p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="span4">
                        <h2>Heading</h2>
                        <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risks. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui. </p>
                        <p><a class="btn" href="#">View details &raquo;</a></p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="span4">
                        <h2>Heading</h2>
                        <p>Donec sed odio dui. Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Vestibulum id ligula porta felis euismod semper. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus.</p>
                        <p><a class="btn" href="#">View details &raquo;</a></p>
                    </div>
                 </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane fade" id="about">
            about
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane fade" id="services">
            services
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane fade" id="contact">
            contact
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane fade" id="new_patient">
            new patient form
        </div>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 3):

I had to add the transition script file and include "fade in" classes to make it work. See the fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/johnpapa/qSqpD/

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you have to wrap the .nav-tabs in another div with class .tabbable

Comment: that fixed the issue for the active link i was having...it wasn't focusing on the first tab item when the page loaded and now it does....but still the tabs don't seem to work at all.  In the URL bar field I can see the Node ID it's calling...example index.html#home.  It's just not switching the display of that div.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the relevant html you need for bootstrap togglable tabs:

```
...
<link href="/static/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="/static/bootstrap/css/bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet">
...
<div class="tabbable">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
        <li class="active"><a href="#tab1" data-toggle="tab">tab1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab2" data-toggle="tab">tab2</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="tab-content">
        <div id="tab1" class="tab-pane active">tab1 content</div>
        <div id="tab2" class="tab-pane">tab2 content</div>
    </div>
</div>
...
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">google.load("jquery", "1.7");</script>
<script src="/static/bootstrap/js/bootstrap-tab.js"></script>
...
```

And here is an example implementation on [jfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ivobos/fuBK6/)